# Difference from sum of column separately from different tables having same columns in sql

Tags: sql, database, oracle

I have 2 tables with same columns TABLE A and TABLE B with columns QUANTITY and AMOUNT.

For single column difference i used this -

```
SELECT ( 
(SELECT SUM(QUANTITY) FROM TABLE A ) -  (SELECT SUM(QUANTITY) FROM TABLE B )
) 
AS DIFF FROM DUAL;
```

I want the difference of QUANTITY and AMOUNT columns.

```
SELECT SUM(QUANTITY) AS SUM1, SUM(AMOUNT) SUM2 FROM TABLE A;

SELECT SUM(QUANTITY) AS SUM3, SUM(AMOUNT) SUM4 FROM TABLE B;
```

I want to achieve-

```
SELECT (SUM1 - SUM3) AS DIFF1, (SUM2 - SUM4) AS DIFF2;
```

Can i do it in single select query or should i go for function or something else??

Thanks for any help in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can be simply extended to

```
SELECT 
(SELECT SUM(QUANTITY) FROM A ) -  (SELECT SUM(QUANTITY) FROM B )
AS DIFF_SUM,
(SELECT SUM(AMOUNT) FROM A ) -  (SELECT SUM(AMOUNT) FROM B )
AS DIFF_QUANT FROM DUAL;
```

Another, perhaps more readable way to do this:

```
WITH a1 AS
(SELECT SUM(QUANTITY) AS SUM1, SUM(AMOUNT) SUM2 FROM A),
b1 AS
(SELECT SUM(QUANTITY) AS SUM3, SUM(AMOUNT) SUM4 FROM B)
SELECT (SUM1 - SUM3) AS DIFF1, (SUM2 - SUM4) AS DIFF2 FROM a1, b1;
```

If you want to really combine them, here's a third way:

```
SELECT SUM(Quantity), SUM(Amount)
FROM
(SELECT Quantity, Amount FROM A
UNION ALL
SELECT -Quantity, -Amount FROM B)
```

Comment: Thanks for quick reply. what if i have around 10 columns in both the table. should i extend the same for 10 columns??? will there not be any performance issue???

Comment: I added a third one that really combines them and should be less tedious to write for a lot of columns. If you want to be able to dynamically handle different numbers of columns you will probably have to look into `PL/SQL` and `EXECUTE IMMEDIATE`, but that's not something you want to go into unless you have a really good reason.

Answer (score 0):

OR:

```
SELECT 
SUM(A.AMOUNT) AS SUMAMOUNTA
,SUM(A.QUANTITY) AS SUMQTYA
,SUM(B.AMOUNT) AS SUMAMOUNTB
,SUM(B.QUANTITY) AS SUMQTYB
,SUM(A.QUANTITY) - SUM(B.QUANTITY) AS DIFFQTY
,SUM(A.AMOUNT) - SUM(B.AMOUNT) DIFFSUM
FROM 
TABLEA A, TABLEB B;
```